# error in implementing completion in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
  let mailComposeViewController = self.configuredMailComposeViewController(randomNumber, email: email!)
   if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
   {
         self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion { () -> Void in

              self.securityCode(randomNumber, email: email!)
         })
     }
     else
     {
          self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
     }
```

Comment: error is coming as "used of unresolved identifier 'completion'"

Comment: You are missing colon after `completion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using completion incorrectly. Use it like this

```
self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated:true) { () -> Void in
             self.securityCode(randomNumber, email: email!)
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot but it is not automatically sending the mail. It only present the mail view controller with the preloaded detail  and we have to click 'send' button... i want i should send it automatically..how can i do this

Comment: You can not send the email automatically without the user pressing the send button. It would be considered against user's privacy.

Comment: @hatim Also, if this answer has helped you, please upvote and accept it so that it will be helpful to future users as well.

Comment: understood thanks a lot for helping @iosDev82 and sorry i can not upVote because it is not accepting my vote may be i am new user thats why.